# Deploying war with dependency resulting in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, deployment, wildfly

I want to use the Enities provided by my data-handler in
my controller-test project. The data-handler is set as an dependency
in controller-test and I get no compile errors, however, when I want to
deploy it I get this exception:

```
Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.test.SomeEntityRepo from [Module deployment.controller-test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:229)
    ... 7 more
```

When I put SomeEntity and SomeEntityRepo into the Controller-test project
everything works as it should.

It's a really simple setup and I just started to work with EE and DI
so I am really frustrated.

I copied the key parts of the structure from one of the wildfly quickstart samples. Wildfly 8.2 and 9.0 give the same exception.

Please help :(

Project data-handler:

Class: SomeEntity

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  protected long id;
  // Getter and Setter
}
```

Class: SomeEntityRepo

```
@Stateless
public class SomeEntityRepo {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public SomeEntity findOne(long id) {
        return em.find(SomeEntity.class, id);
    }
}
```

Class Resource

```
public class Resources {

    @PersistenceContext
    @Produces
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

XML: Persistance

```
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/TestDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Project: Controller-test

```
@RequestScoped
public class TestClass {

    @Inject
    private SomeEntityRepo repo;

    public void test() {
        repo.find(0L);
    }
}
```

Addition:

Afterwards my War looks like this:

```
   controller-test.war
   ^-- WEB-INF
       ^-- classes
       ^-- lib
           ^-- data-handler.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
               ^-- com
                   ^--test
                      ^-- SomeEntity
                      ^-- SomeEntityRepo
```

Comment: which version of maven are you using? and please provide the pom.xml that is in your project root

Comment: Hello Ramin,
[Here is my pom](http://pastebin.com/1fwNH2k9) and my Maven version is 3.3.3.

Comment: have you run `mvn install` for `data-handler` to install it on your local repository, so that you can depend on it?

Comment: take a look at [this cookbook](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) for common commands

Comment: Hi Ramin, I already ran maven-install for data-handler and after that for controller-test. It went through both with "Build successful" after that I tried
Run As -> Run on Server.(eclipse) I use an "out of the box" Wildfly Server that I configured inside eclipse.

Comment: I added my .war structure after mvn install.